# Copy text and paste inside iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, clipboard, zeroclipboard

I've one dropdown with some values. I want to paste dropdown selected item value inside iframe textbox's.

My understanding is whenever user select dropdown item. At that time we can get selected item value and store it in one variable or clipboard. Then we can paste inside iframe. but we don't have permission to get iframe textbox's id or name or class. So without those things can we paste clipboard value?

Please advice how we can do this type of challenges.

You're answer will appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to access a third-party iframe content. You can't, please read about [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: Yes right its third-party. but we can able to do manually copy paste. but i want auto made. is it possible?. What we can do we can have one dropdown. and dropdown selected value we can copy in our clipboard and whenever we click on textbox inside iframe at that same time we can paste that's it. but i don't have textbox id, name and classes. please advice how we can proceed

Comment: When pasting, you'd need an exact reference where to past. However, you can't get it from a third-party's page, hence not possible.

Comment: Ok. Can you suggest me copy automated. See found one example but its promoting alert box then we can copy from alertbox manually. its not good enough for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: The problem is, that you can't automate the pasting ...

Comment: Ok. I will do paste manual. But can you please suggest copy automate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92638/discussion-between-jatin-gadhiya-and-teemu).

Comment: Please don't access user's clipboard automatically, they might loose some important information.

Comment: No problem. this feature will not for all user or social. its only for limited. please suggest copy to  clipboard automatically when dropdown item change if you have

Comment: There's a [ton of these questions already](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]copy+to+clipboard) ; ).

Comment: I've already tried some of this.. but its not working properly. I don't want promote and copy manually. I want whenever select item from dropdown and inside dropdown change event automated copy to clipboard that's it.

Comment: Hello Teemu.. I've done automated copying..:)